# Is there any way to "pre-load" my sequence so that the preview is smooth?

Tags: premiere

So as I'm getting into the 2 minute mark of my video and starting to add a few effects, the preview/program window is becoming very choppy. It's hard to see how things are going because of the choppiness. Is there any way I can like "pre-load" or "pre-render" everything so that when I play it, it's smooth?

I sometimes now have to export my video to MP4 and watch it there in order to get a smooth preview and feel as to what's really going on.

I'm running macOS High Sierra on a MB Pro w/ Retina (2015 edition), 2.8 GHz i7, 16GB DDR3 and a 1TB SSD.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Just found a few tips that I had been looking for. Couldn't necessarily figure out the terms I was looking for. A few things to look for if anyone else is interesting:

- Rendering in and out points to speed it up
- Reducing the preview quality from Full to 1/2, etc.